# Why +true is not equal to true.valueOf?

Tags: javascript, coercion

```
+true // result: 1

true.valueOf() // result: true

+true === true.valueOf() // result: false
```

In Javascript Type Coersion, the function called for evaluation is valueOf(). But if the function is called explicity it returns a different value.

Comment: I don't understand. `+true` coerces a boolean to a number. `true.valueOf()` returns `true`. Of course `1` does not **strictly equal** `true`.

Comment: You are comparing boolean and integer values and wondering why that is not the same? What was the question?

Comment: Why true.valueOf() doesn't returns 1

Comment: Why would it? `.valueOf()` is not defined to return numbers. It returns the primitive value of an object. In case of a bool, it returns a bool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: I was reading a book Expert Javascript. I didn't understand the line, "Without specifying a hint for the internal DefaultValue function, JavaScript assumes you want a number. This results in a call to valueOf() instead". So my assumption was .valueOf() would return a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the function called for evaluation is valueOf()

Not always. `valueOf()` is only meaningful for non-primitive types, since it is defined to return the primitive value of the given object. `true` by itself is a Boolean primitive and as such calling `true.valueOf()` would be completely redundant.

The unary `+` and `-` sign operators always return a number by definition. Since a Boolean quite conveniently converts to a number, it only makes sense that `+true` returns 1.

There is no reason `+true` and `true.valueOf()` should both correspond to the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Type Coersion in Javascript happens if `==` is used, which is *kinda loose* comparison operator.

`===` is **strict** comparison operator which *doesn't* coerce the types when comparing so it remains an integer and the other one bool

```
+true === true.valeOf() // false
+true == true.valueOf() // true
```

[Docs:](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm)

> The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==)
>   operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the
>   same to be considered equal.
>
> Why true.valueOf() doesn't returns 1

The answer is `true.valueOf` returns `true`, which is the primitive value of a Boolean object. Also the quote is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf)

> The valueOf method of Boolean returns the primitive value of a Boolean
>   object or literal Boolean as a Boolean data type.

What does `+true` do:

`+true` is same as `Number(true)` and it is a well known fact that `0` is `false` and `1` is `true` in almost every language. In fact in C++ they *are* used as booleans.

Comment: @WBAR What? An instance of X can be the value of Y. What did you mean?

Comment: I think the OP understands how `===` works and is asking why `+true` doesn't return the exact same thing as `true.valueOf()`.

Comment: Type coercion, like forcing a value to a primitive type, does happen in many places, not only in `==`???

Comment: @Bergi I'm not that deep into the language, so didn't know that. From what I learnt answering here, and from the context, I made that statement. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for **strict** comparison you should do like this:

```
Number(true.valueOf()) === +true
```